# I can't change the column Kind to Type on the firestore database collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to change the column with the name **kind** to  **type** but I do not know how to change it

**image1**
[image: image1]
even if I choose **map** or a **number** the type stays always as a string.

**image2**
[image: image 2]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change the language of the operating system from French to English. Or even simpler, change your browser's language to English. That way you'll have Type and not Kind.

Comment: thankyou you save my time  i just changed the browser language

Comment: Hey Abdessamad. Can I help you with other information?